# Android Studio choreographer.java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new in Android Studio and Firebase.  The error shows when I try to build the app.  I had tried invalidate/restart, clean project, and reinstall the android studio but it does not solve the problem.

[image].

**Here is description Logcat.**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The reason for the error is AndroidStudio cannot see the 'DisplayEventReceiver.java'  in your app. The 'Choreographer.java' is in the "android/view" directory ("android.view" package). DisplayEventReceiver.java should be in the same directory and AndroidStudio is not seeing it.

Comment: can I know more about this 'DisplayEventReceiver.java should be in the same directory '? Sorry, I am not familiar with android studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

choreographer.java is a class of Android and Android studio can't see other android classes (android.*) in your app... But don't worry it works fine... If you have any problem review your code.

Comment: Is that mean error does not affect the application?